# can't get value from ConcurrentHashMap - Java

Tags: java, smartfoxserver

I'm need little help, i can't figured it why i can't take value what i want it. here the code I'm trying to do

RouletteExtension.java

```
public class RouletteExtension extends SFSExtension {
   private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,PlayerHandler> players = null;
   @Override
   public void init() {
      players = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,PlayerHandler>();
   }
   public ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, PlayerHandler> getPlayers() {
      return players;
   }
   public void setPlayers(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, PlayerHandler> players) {
      this.players = players;
   }
}
```

PlayerHandler.java

```
public class PlayerHandler {
   private int id = 0;
   User sfsUser = null;
   public PlayerHandler() {}
   public PlayerHandler(int id, User sfsUser) {
      this.id = id;
      this.sfsUser = sfsUser;
   }

   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public User getSfsUser() {
      return sfsUser;
   }
   public void setSfsUser(User sfsUser) {
      this.sfsUser = sfsUser;
   }
}
```

BettingHandler.java

```
public class BettingHandler extends BaseClientRequestHandler {
   @Override
   public void handleClientRequest(User user, ISFSObject params) {
      RouletteExtension gameExt = (RouletteExtension) getParentExtension();
      PlayerHandler a = gameExt.getPlayers().get(user.getId());
      trace ("testOne = ", gameExt.getPlayers());
      trace ("testTwo = ",user.getId());
      trace ("testThree = ", a);
   }
}
```

**this script for SFS2X serverside**, I'm new in java actually so i wanna know what value `a` is, when I'm trace in zone monitor just show up this

```
{RouletteExt}: testOne =  {}
{RouletteExt}: testTwo =  1
```

**testThree** not show up, so something wrong with this, can someone tell me how to fix this, and explain what happening in here, thanks

Comment: Well, `players` seems to be empty ... then `a` is `null` and you run into a NullPointerException which you seem to swallow somewhere.

Comment: Could it be that your `trace` method cannot handle the case where the second argument is null (as we believe `a` is in the third call to `trace()`)?

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Comment: i don't know either, is to debugger using eclipse, choose **debug as > 1 Java Aplication?** if so when I'm trying to debug **1 Java Aplicaton** not showed up, so I'm using trace to look what inside `a` is. - @OleV.V.

Comment: More code needed I think. My guess is that you are calling `setPlayers()` at some point and accidentally overwriting your hashmap.

Comment: Yes, :-) but there’s more to it than that. This is not the forum for teaching you to use the debugger, :-/ even though I think it’s something every programmer should learn. :-)

Comment: What output exactly were you expecting from your code if it were correct?

Comment: i see, i will looking another way to debug. what output i'm expecting is to create object player, where it's id stored when **BettingHandler.java** being called. - @OleV.V.

Comment: I’m unsure whether I understand. In the code you’ve given I see nowhere that you are creating an object player (as in, for example, `new PlayerHandler(myId, myUser)`). If you’re doing this nowhere, it’s probably part of the problem. :-)